# Should a 20A outlet circuit have #14 wire on it?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am replacing all the old outlets in my house and came across an issue. I have 4 hot/black wires, 4 white/neutral wires pushed into the back of an outlet and one bare ground wire screwed onto the side. 3 black wires are 14 gauge, and one I believe is 12. Same with the white. The circuit breaker is 20 amp. This circuit supports a one GFCI outlet, the microwave, fridge, and at least 3 regular outlets. From everything I have read, the 12 gauge wire is not in code. Is that correct?

If this is all fine, what electrical outlet can I use to replace this one? Is it just best to pigtail them? Thanks for your help![image]

This is what the back of the old receptacle looks like. [image]

Comment: White _are_ neutral. Did you mean bare ground? Also, you won't have a single larger wire in a situation like that. All wires in a cable are typically the same gauge. If they're not, the _smaller_ wires are more likely to be illegal. I suggest a read through a basic wiring book if you're brand new. Don't be guessing! :)

Comment: Need to change to a 15 amp breaker, or change all wires to 12 gauge(your pick).  Kitchens are suppose to be on 20 amp circuits now.    Microwave(if good size) plus the fridge might be pushing a 15 amp breaker to trip.  Might be an idea to think about re wire the kitchen.

Comment: Taking pictures of before undoing wires is a very good idea for you to see how they went, and to post here so we see what you have, if you have problems.

Comment: Please revise to make corrections and add new information. It shouldn't be down here. Please take the [tour] for more understanding of how this site works.

Comment: [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/244915/edit) your question, and use the button with the 'mountains' icon to add pics.

Comment: The loosely wrapped ground wire needs to be fixed - and you should also look for the other 2 which should be in there too. I would definitely pigtail those to just bring one set of black/white/ground out to the receptacle.

Comment: @crip659 write that up as an answer. (also, apologize I may have flagged your comment accidentally on my phone, not sure, but your comment is 100% the answer 15A or rewire)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   Seeing those new pictures, just wondering if having the OP get an electrician instead is better, or at least a good book.  Second outlet seems to be messed up with white on ground screw and bare ground wrapped around it.

Comment: Just an FYI, I didn’t do any of the wiring just simply replacing old fixtures that have been painted over. This is the only outlet that is so funky. The second outlet with the bare wire was the new outlet I was trying to replace the old one with, so had just moved the bare wire over before I saw the mess.

Comment: You should hire an electrician, at the very least to look at all this and make recommendations.  You have 14ga wires on a 20A breaker.  You have an outlet's push terminals being used as a terminal block for 8 wires.  You have a ground wire covered in white paint, and another ground wire wrapped loosely around it over top of the paint.  With this many problems in one box, you have to assume there are more, possibly worse problems elsewhere.  If you have bitten off replacing "all" the outlets in your home, that would be a good time to have someone experienced inspect them.

Comment: Ok, last comment. I suspect the wiring is   Connecting power to the outlet and possibly fan in the microwave. When the microwave was installed they didn't install the blower correctly, so it wouldn’t surprise me if this was done wrong too. Would it make sense to daisy chain the microwave outlet to another outlet in the same wall?

Comment: A "Spec Grade" receptacle ($3, in its own little box) will take 4 screws per side, without trouble and without backstabbing. There's nothing wrong with a triple split (4 wires per side) if there's enough room in the box for the wires.

Comment: I don't see side screws on the receptacle. Were there receptacles which only accepted wires in spring loaded backstabs?

Comment: No, side screws. These were old receptacles and only had a spring loaded backstabs.

Answer (score 2):

The answer with your explanation is no but I will rephrase should a 20 amp circuit have 14awg wire.

There are legal outlets with 20 amp breakers using 14awg wire.

There are exceptions in the code for motor circuits that allow using a larger breaker for starting.

You used the term outlet this can be a receptacle but it can also be the line from a disconnect

In the old days 12 Awg wire did not fit in stabs, today  however there are more manufacturers that are UL listed getting there hardware certified for 12 awg wire.

Newer receptacles may not have the #14 max warning in fact the one in the photo is one that #12 solid is allowed.

So the last possible variation can I put a backstabbed duplex 15 amp receptacle on a 20 amp circuit, well yes, if the receptacle allows #12 a single duplex backstabbed receptacle is code compliant.

But in my opinion no self respecting electricians use stabs on receptacles, I should love them I am sure failed backstabbed receptacles paid for my sons college .

stabs are the #1 electrical failure in my experience and most likely the reasoning behind increasing modern code to require AFCI protection where it was originally required to prevent electric blanket fires in bedrooms.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the first outlet in the circuit, with the many wires.

One set of black and white and bare/green ground will come from the panel and will be hot/live with the breaker on.

the other wires/cables should go the the other outlets/maybe lights.

If any 14 gauge wires on this circuit, you are only allowed a 15 amp breaker.  If all are 12 gauge or bigger, 20 amp breaker is allowed.

Kitchens are supposed to be on 20 amp breakers, more than one breaker for the outlets.  And they are supposed to be GFCI protected.

Find the cable from the panel and those wires can be placed on one set of screws on the outlet.  The other cables for the other outlets should be pigtailed together with a short wire going to the second set of screws on the outlet.  Black to black to brass screw, white to white to silver screws.

Grounds pigtailled together and to green screw on outlet.

Never white used on ground connections, only green or bare wires.

You seem to have too many kitchen outlets on one breaker.  Bad idea some people do is to use a bigger(20amp) breaker when a proper(if having 14 gauge wire) 15 amp breaker trips often.  Your kitchen circuit is likely to have had this problem in the pass.